# JOOQ MySQL TEXT DataType

Tags: mysql, jooq

I'm trying to generate this simple SQL with JOOQ and for some reason I can't get it done.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    F TEXT
);
```

I expected it to be something like

```
dsl.createTable(name("T"))
   .column("F", MySQLDataType.TEXT);
```

Unfortunately, `MySQLDataType` is deprecated (`Do not reference this type directly from client code. Referencing this type before the SQLDataType class has been initialised may lead to deadlocks!`). So I tried

```
dsl.createTable(name("T"))
   .column(field("F TEXT"));
```

But I get the following SQL instead, which is not legal.

```
CREATE TABLE `T` (F text other null );
```

Any hints?

Comment: Use `SQLDataType` from this package `import org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType;`, e.g. `SQLDataType.TEXT.nullable(false)`

Comment: @AamirR There's no field `TEXT` in `SQLDataType`. See, https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.9.6/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html

Comment: Can you try `SQLDataType.CLOB` instead, check the resulting datatype in database, hope it helps!

Comment: @AamirR With `SQLDataType.CLOB` the result is as expected `CREATE TABLE T (F text null);` so this actually solves the question. So, please, update your answer so I can accept it. One thing is bothering me, though: what if I wanted `LONGTEXT`, instead? What if I wanted another vendor specific type?

Comment: Glad it helped, Updated my answer as will with new information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/util/mysql/MySQLDataType.html) says

> Use the corresponding [SQLDataType](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html) instead.

You can use `.column("ColumnName", SQLDataType.CLOB)` for MySQL `TEXT` datatype.

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

> The four TEXT **(CLOB)** types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold.

If you use `SQLDataType.CLOB(LENGTH)` with vendor specific length, you will result in `TINYTEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `LONGTEXT`

*Note that MySQL refers `CLOB` as `TEXT`*

Usage examples

```
SQLDataType.INTEGER.identity(true)        // INTEGER Primary key
SQLDataType.VARCHAR(4095).nullable(false) // VARCHAR(4095) NOT NULL
SQLDataType.CHAR(10)                      // CHAR(10)
SQLDataType.BLOB                          // BLOB
SQLDataType.CLOB)                         // TEXT, same as blob, but with character encoding associated
SQLDataType.CLOB(16777215)                // MEDIUMTEXT
SQLDataType.CLOB(4294967295)              // LONGTEXT
```